# What is preventing my wpf application from finding a resource that it has already used

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a multi-project application.  In the startup project there is little more (at present) than a call to Application_Startup.  The xaml is defined like this;

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="Application_Startup">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and the application_startup event itself is defined like so;

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    Dim controller As New LoginController(New LoginService)
    _CanLaunchMainApplication = controller.StartLoginDialog
    If _CanLaunchMainApplication Then

    Else
       Application.Current.Shutdown
    End If
End Sub
```

When I start the application a login dialog is displayed, which currently will return false. I have set a breakpoint on the Application.Current.Shutdown line of the if statement which is reached.  On pressing continue I would expect the application to shutdown, instead it throws an unhandled exception of type IOException stating that it cannot locate resource 'appplication_startup', which strikes me as a little odd given that that is exactly where we just happen to be in the execution of the code.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

EDIT

Here is the relevant Stack Trace.

```
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
  at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
```

Comment: I don't see any resources defined in XAML or in code. The StartupUri isn't the name of a resource, it's the name of a method. Where does the exception occur, what is its stacktrace? Do you try to create/access a resource named `application_startup` anywhere? Please post the relevant code

Comment: Added StackTrace to the original question.

Comment: StartupUri should point to a resource like your application's main window class. Instead, you put the name of an event handler method.

Comment: The following msdn  page seems to suggest that you can have an event handler as a stratup uri;  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx   and there are code project articles displaying a similar approach.

Comment: That's a different property, it's the `Startup` property where you put the name of the event handler. You used the `StartupUri` property, which expect the URI to a resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you put the name of the event handler on the [StartupUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead of the [Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) property.

*Startup* expects the name of an event handler on the application object itself, while *StartupUri* expects the Uri to the resource (eg Window) that will be displayed once application startup finishes.

Put the name of the event handler in `Startup`. You don't need to use *StartupUri* at all if you create your main window inside the Startup event handler, as shown in the sample on the documentation page of the Startup property